# Oracle: How to get list of objects accessible to the user?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, system-tables

I want to get list of all objects which is accessible to the login user. The list should include Table, Sequence, Function, Procedure, View, Sequence, Index, Trigger etc.

I am using Oracle 11g and Oracle 12c. My requirement is that the owner of the db objects grant privileges to other user, so that user can access those objects by running select or other query. I did try earlier `dba_objects` but DBA does not allow to grant permission for `dba_objects` to the user. So I am looking for different solution.

I did try `all_objects` that list of all objects accessible to the user, but It lists the Table, View, Index and Sequence only.

Either I am missing something or its returns it only.

Can anybody suggest me correct way to get all accessible objects to the user?

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

`ALL_OBJECTS` lists all the object types, at least those which you need, except triggers, for which you can query `ALL_TRIGGERS`.

Comment: `ALL_TRIGGERS` contains entries that are already in `ALL_OBJECTS`, its just a filtered list. If they do not show up in `ALL_OBJECTS` there is something else wrong.